# JavaScript/CSS: How to resize (scale) window content

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any way to scale window content with javascript and/or CSS 2 ? Im looking for something similiar to CSS 3 - transform:scale(x,y). Lets say that I have a div, filled with some text and with fixed width/height. When I change the size of my browser window, div will resize but the text will not change its size. I want the text to squeeze just like it does in CSS 3 which unfortunately is not supported by my browser.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: what's exactly "your browser" vendor and version?

Comment: I can't answer you on this one :( Im working with some kind of a decoding device with dedicated built-in browser. The only thing I know is that it supports JS and CSS 2.

Comment: does it supports mediaqueries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use mediaqueries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

depending on the size of the browser window you can define several css rules, in particular use `max/min-width` query

Comment: Thanks. Mediaqueries seems to be the best solution for my problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps: Cross Browser CSS Transforms – even in IE - http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/